# Exactly where should initialisation code go in a lambda? i.e. when using Sentry

Tags: aws-lambda, sentry

we use and love sentry, however, i've noticed sometimes it doesnt contain the cloudwatch logs link.  This is because, the lambda handler never got called, we crashed before it that.

and the reason for that, is because we do things like definining e.g. a client:

```
lambda_client = boto3.client("lambda")
```

BEFORE the handler is called.  Now; why do we do that? I was told this is better for resource usage if the lambda gets called again, and is still alive?  Now i'm not sure however. Are there any resources to learn about this?

However; typically the other things that are crashing are getting env variables when we forgot to set it in the template, or other connections failing to init.

Anyway; I also feel that moving all our initialisation code/variables into the handler function, is also bad to do that JUST because of the way sentry works. So thats why i'd like to know what is right, and then consider whether this is a sentry bug, or otherwise?  (they do say this is the case, it may well be how the aws api works)

Of course, if you have some terminal build failure, and you have missing modules, then sentry can never catch that anyway. but thats fine - it's generally pretty obvious when it's that borked.  And you should catch that with e.g. "sam local invoke" etc.